# Count words in a dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with sentences in the first column and I want to count the words in it :

Input :

```
Foo bar
bar example
lalala foo
example sentence foo
```

Output :

```
foo       3
bar       2
example   2
lalala    1
sentence  1
```

Is there a simple way to do this ?

If not, how should I do it ? I see two ways :

```
Append all the sentences in one huge string
And then count the words somehow
```

(seems very inefficient)
Or

```
Split the column in multiple columns on spaces " " (I know there's a package for that, can't remember which one)
And then rbind each columns into one
```

Comment: Do you really just have a one-column `data.frame`? Try `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(mydf, "V1", " ", "long")[, .N, tolower(V1)]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As in your second approach. We can `split` the columns on empty space (`" "`) and then use `table` to count the frequencies of each word. Also it seems that the output should be case insensitive, hence converting the column into lower case before splitting.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and the target column is `V1`.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(df$V1), " ")))

 #bar  example      foo   lalala sentence 
 #  2        2        3        1        1
```

If this needs to be in a dataframe,

```
data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(df$V1), " "))))

#      Var1 Freq
#1      bar    2
#2  example    2
#3      foo    3
#4   lalala    1
#5 sentence    1
```

**EDIT**

As per OP's update in comments if there is a `score` column for each sentence and we need to `sum` them for every word.

Adding a reproducible example,

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("Foo bar", "bar example", "lalala foo","example sentence foo"), 
                 score = c(2, 3, 1, 4))
df

#                    v1 score
#1              Foo bar     2
#2          bar example     3
#3           lalala foo     1
#4 example sentence foo     4
```

One way of solving this is with packages `splitstackshape` and `dplyr`. We convert each sentence into a long dataframe using `cSplit` and then summarise for every word calculating the frequency (`n()`) and the `sum`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
cSplit(df, "v1", sep = " ", direction = "long") %>%
      group_by(tolower(v1)) %>%
      summarise(Count = n(), 
                ScoreSum = sum(score))

#  tolower(v1) Count ScoreSum
#        (chr) (int)    (dbl)
#1         foo     3        7
#2         bar     2        5
#3     example     2        7
#4      lalala     1        1
#5    sentence     1        4
```

---

Or using only `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate_rows(v1, sep = ' ') %>%
  group_by(v1 = tolower(v1)) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(), 
            ScoreSum = sum(score))
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I had another column in my input dataframe with a score for each sentence, and wanted to keep the score of each word (by computing the sum) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
df$freq<-str_count(df$word,'\\w+')
```

Comment: You need to add str_count(df$word,'\\w+')+1 as one word would return 0

Comment: This just counts how many times the regex pattern occurs per value in the vector. They wanted the frequency of each word across the whole vector